# display only selected terms in custom node template

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, theming

How can I change the below code to display only the selected terms in the node. right now all terms which are defined in the vocabulary is displayed

```
<?php 
$items = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('test_categories');
$taxonomy = taxonomy_get_tree($items->vid);
foreach($taxonomy as $key => $items):
  print $items->name;
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print a selected taxonomy value in a node, try this way..

```
$node = node_load($nid);
//If you have multiple values use foreach.
$tid = $node->yourfieldname['und'][0]['tid'];//if you are using term reference.
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
print $term->name;
```

Comment: I'm using multiple values and i tried but still not working with me

Comment: did u tried it in a loop..?? can u show d code..??

Answer (score 0):

For specific node you need to use **$info = node_load($nid)** where you find your field value using $info->field_name. Using that field you can use foreach something like foreach($info->field_name as as $key => $items).

Comment: please can you explain it in example